# Return event in HERE

Tags: javascript, events, here-api

I am converting to HERE maps API 3.1 and haven't been able to find the same functionality in HERE that exists in both Google and Bing to return an event.

Bing: return Microsoft.Maps.Events.addThrottledHandler (_map, 'viewchangeend', callBack, 100);
Google: return google.maps.event.addListener(_map, 'bounds_changed', callBack);

What is the equivalent in HERE?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for mapviewchange or mapviewchangeend Events below is the information:

Mapviewchange is called on each animation step in the process of changing a state of the viewport. In many cases, this operation is excessive. For example, updating a UI element with the current zoom level multiple times each time the user double-clicks on the map is inefficient.

```
// Displays current zoom level to the end user:
function displayZoomLevel() {...}

// A listener updates the map zoom level on each map view change
// -- this occurs more than 20 times on a double-click on the map, 
// inefficient and to be avoided:
map.addEventListener('mapviewchange', function () {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();

    // This function is called more than 20 times on a double-click on the map!
    displayZoomLevel(zoom);
});
```

mapviewchangeend, on the other hand, is called only once, when the viewport change is complete, therefore, we recommend using this event to update the map viewport:

/

```
* 
    Displays current zoom level to the end user 
 */
function displayZoomLevel() {...}

// A listener updates the map zoom level -- it is called once when the map 
// view change is complete.
map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', function () {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();

    // The function that displays the zoom level is called only once, 
    // after zoom level changed
    displayZoomLevel(zoom);
});
```

The mapviewchangeend event is a 'debounced' version of mapviewchange, so, as a rule, it is more efficient to use mapviewchangeend